# "exec not found" when using variable in exec

Tags: linux, shell

I met a strange problem.

```
mkfifo "spch2008"
exec 100<>"spch2008"
```

It's OK. But, when i use variable to replace "100", error occurs.

exec: 100: not found

```
PIPE_ID=100
mkfifo "spch2008"
exec ${PIPE_ID}<>"spch2008"
```

I don't know the reason.  please hlep me,thanks.

Comment: While there is no prohibition on the file descriptor number, there is a general use of the **next available** when using file redirection.  (that is `3` if it is your first redirect) (e.g. `stdin - 0`, `stdout - 1`, `stderr - 2`, `your redirect - 3`) As to your question, it is a strange question, but it appears you are running into limitations imposed by the fact that shell variables are not typed (e.g., `int`, `char`, etc..). Your use of `exec $var<>fifo` has no way of insuring `${PIPE_ID}` is in fact a valid number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is caused by shell not performing variable expansion on the left side of the redirection operator. You can use a workaround:

```
eval exec "${PIPE_ID}"'<>"spch2008"'
```

It will force the shell to do variable expansion, producing

```
eval exec 100'<>"spch2008"'
```

Then the `eval` built-in will feed the command to the shell, which will effectively execute

```
exec 100<>"spch2008"
```

Answer (score 0):

I/O redirection doesn't allow variables to specify the file descriptors generally, not just in the context of the `<>` redirection.

Consider:

```
$ cat > errmsg                     # Create script
echo "$@" >&2                      # Echo arguments to standard error
$ chmod +x errmsg                  # Make it executable
$ x=2
$ ./errmsg Hi                      # Writing on standard error
Hi
$ ./errmsg Hi ${x}>&1              # Writing on standard error
Hi 2
$ ./errmsg Hi 2>&1                 # Redirect standard error to standard output
Hi
$ ./errmsg Hi 2>/dev/null          # Standard error to /dev/null
$ ./errmsg Hi ${x}>/dev/null       # Standard output to /dev/null
Hi 2
$
```